# How do I create columns on WijGrid using Knockout at run time based on server output?

Tags: knockout.js, wijmo

In every example of the WijGrid the columns are created manually in an array like this:

```
<table id="dataGrid" data-bind="wijgrid: {
                                          data: dataRows,
                                          pageSize: pageSize,
                                          pageIndex: pageIndex,
                                          totalRows: totalRows,
                                          allowPaging: true,
                                          allowSorting: true,
                                          sorted: sorted,
                                          pageIndexChanged: paged,
                                          columns: [
                                                   { sortDirection: 'ascending', dataType: 'number', dataFormatString: 'n0', headerText: 'ID', width: 60 },
                                                   { headerText: 'Product' },
                                                   { dataType: 'currency', headerText: 'Price', width: 100},
                                                   { dataType: 'number', dataFormatString: 'n0', headerText: 'Units', width: 100}]
                                                   }">
</table>
```

OR in the WijGrid object like this:

```
$('#activejobs').wijgrid({
    columns: [
        { headerText:'Customer',allowSort:true, dataType:'string' },
        { headerText:'Job Number',allowSort:true, dataType:'string'},
                    { headerText:'Scheduled Completion',allowSort:true, dataType:'datetime', sortDirection:'ascending'},
            { headerText:'Description',allowSort:false, dataType:'string', ensurePxWidth:true, width:250 },
            { headerText:'Total Hours',allowSort:true, dataType:'number'}
    ],
    columnsAutogenerationMode: "merge",
    dynamic:true
});
```

When using knockout, however, I can't find a way to edit or manipulate automatically generated columns based on server data. For example, the project I am working on returns the amount of hours that a particular job will spend in each manufacturing process, or department.  The customer can add or delete processes or departments over time, so I cannot guarantee that these columns will always be the same, nor can I guarantee their data type, sorting options, classes, formatting and etc.

With knockout, I can iterate through my data and add the columns on demand, and although this works well, I have no way of changing each column parameter.

Below is the code I am using:

```
var viewModel = {
    pageSize: ko.observable(10),
    pageIndex: ko.observable(0),
    sortCommand: ko.observable("EndDate asc"),
    dataRows: ko.observableArray([]),
    totalRows: ko.observable(0),
    sorted:function(e,data){
        viewModel.sortCommand(data.sortCommand);
    },
    paged:function(e,data){
        viewModel.pageIndex(data.newPageIndex);
    },
    load:function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/workcenters/get-active-jobs/",
            datatype:'json',
            data:{
                format: 'json',
                inlinecount: "allpages",
                orderby: viewModel.sortCommand(),
                top: viewModel.pageSize(),
                skip: viewModel.pageIndex() * viewModel.pageSize(),
                page:viewModel.pageIndex()
            },
            success:function(result){
                var data = result.d.results;
                var arr = [];
                $.each(data,function(i){
                    var collection = data[i];
                    arr.push(new job(collection));                      
                });
                viewModel.totalRows(result.d.__count);
                viewModel.dataRows(arr);
            }
        });
    }
};
var job = function(data){
var collection = {
        "Customer Name": ko.observable(data.customername),
        "Job Number": ko.observable(data.jobnumber),
        "Delivery Date": ko.observable(data.projectedend),
        Description: ko.observable(data.description),
        Hours: ko.observable(data.hours)
};

var workhoursCollection = data.workhours;
$.each(workhoursCollection,function(i,workhours){
    var heading = workhours.elements.heading;
    collection[heading] = ko.observable(workhours.elements.value);
});
return collection;
};
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#pagesize').wijdropdown();

$('#activejobs').wijgrid({
    allowColSizing:true,
    allowColMoving:true,
    allowKeyboardNavigation:true,
    allowPaging:true,
    allowSorting:true,
    cellStyleFormatter: function(args){
    },
    rowStyleFormatter: function(args){
    },
    columns: [
            { headerText:'Customer',allowSort:true, dataType:'string'        },
            { headerText:'Job Number',allowSort:true, dataType:'string'},
            { headerText:'Scheduled Completion',allowSort:true, dataType:'datetime', sortDirection:'ascending'},
            { headerText:'Description',allowSort:false, dataType:'string', ensurePxWidth:true, width:250 },
            { headerText:'Total Hours',allowSort:true, dataType:'number'}
        ],
    columnsAutogenerationMode: "merge",
    culture:"en",
    dynamic:true,
    highlightCurrentCell: true,
    loadingText:"Please wait a moment...",
    scrollMode:"auto",
    //showGroupArea:true,
    staticRowIndex:0,
    staticColumnIndex:0
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.load();
viewModel.sortCommand.subscribe(function(newValue){
    viewModel.load();
});
viewModel.pageIndex.subscribe(function(newValue){
    viewModel.load();
});
viewModel.pageSize.subscribe(function(newValue){
    viewModel.load();
    $('#pagesize').wijdropdown("refresh");
});
});

function addColumn(rowObject){
var grid = $('#activejobs');
options = grid.wijgrid('option');

grid.wijgrid('destroy');

options.columns.push(rowObject);
grid.wijgrid(options);
}
```

The Object that the server returns looks like this (PHP):

```
d = array(
 'results'=>array{
          "customername"=>$data->name,
      "jobnumber"=>$data->number,
      "projectedend"=>$data->projectedenddate,
      "description"=>$data->description,
      "hours"=>$data->estimatedhours,
       "workhours"=>$workgroupCollection
  }, '__count'=>$count
)
$workgroupCollection = array{   
    'info'=>array('heading'=>$workgroup->name,'name'=>$workgroupName),
    'elements'=>array(
     'name'=>$element,
     'heading'=>$workAreaModel->name,
         'value'=>$hours
    )
}
```

Eventually, I want to use this data to create Bands as well, but the first step is to be able to edit dynamically generated column properties.

Summary: How can I build a wijmo Grid with some default columns, then add new columns at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this link: http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=Grid&sample=Column%20visibility? If you know what all the column possibilities are, you could put them all in the source code HTML on the server as hidden, then toggle the visibility as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have been able to add columns to wijgrid, but I haven't had the time to explain it here.  I did it by loading the columns using Ajax and halting the $(document).ready() until after the AJAX request completes.  There should be a better way and I'll try to look for it once I get further in development.  Working with Wijmo elements put me behind schedule because I always have to reverse engineer their examples to get anything to work.